# How to align a div holder to viewport and other div?

Tags: html, css

I doesn't know how to achieve the following. I have a section that holds 3 images. Those images will be responsive in that section. I would like to align the holder `div` to the left side of the viewport and the right side of the holder div to the container div. See image:

[image]

My markup looks like the following:

```
<section>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x210">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x210">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x210">
    </figure>
</section>
```

Is this possible with css only?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWWyJN

Comment: what holder `div`? are you missing some markup? Doesn't seem to match your image.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. The three figures are wrapped in another div. The grid will show the container to center everything in the viewport (bootstrap grid). @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using flexboxes?  Put `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` on your container and `flex: 1 1 auto;` on your children.  (That should be a simple enough case for IE to get it right. :)